# I want to upload pictures in react native project in android how to choose and upload them in firebase storage in android

Tags: firebase, react-native, file-upload, firebase-storage, photo

I want to upload pictures in react native project  in android how to choose and upload them in firebase storage in android.

Answer (score 0):

```
To upload pictures in a React Native project for Android, you can use the React Native Image Picker library to select images from the user's device and the Firebase SDK to upload the selected images to Firebase Storage.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

First, install the React Native Image Picker and Firebase packages by running the following commands:
npm install --save react-native-image-picker
npm install --save firebase

Then, import the Image Picker and Firebase modules in your React Native component:

import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import firebase from 'firebase';

To select an image, you can use the showImagePicker method of the Image Picker module. This method displays a native image picker component, allowing the user to select an image from their device's photo library or take a new photo with the camera.
Here's an example of how to use showImagePicker:

const options = {
  title: 'Select Avatar',
  storageOptions: {
    skipBackup: true,
    path: 'images',
  },
};

ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.did cancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response. error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.custom button) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.custom button);
  } else {
    const source = { uri: response.uri };

    // You can also display the image using data:
    // const source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

    this.setState({
      avatarSource: source,
    });
  }
});

After the user selects an image, the response object returned by showImagePicker contains the path to the selected image on the user's device. You can then use the Firebase SDK to upload the image to Firebase Storage.
Here's an example of how to do this:

const file = {
  uri: response.uri,
  name: response.fileName,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
};

const storage = firebase.storage();
const storageRef = storage.ref();
const imagesRef = storageRef.child('images');
const imageRef = imagesRef.child(file.name);

imageRef.put(file)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('File uploaded successfully');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error uploading file: ', error);
  });

This code creates a reference to the images folder in Firebase Storage, and then creates a new child reference with the name of the selected image file. It then uses the put method of the child reference to upload the file to Firebase Storage.
```